# Is it possible to add nested grid in existing one?

Tags: jxls

I have collection of objects, and each object contain another collection of object. Is is possible dynamically choose columns and generate xls using GridCommand?

Comment: did you read this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32826794/putting-two-dynamic-grids-beside-each-other-with-jxls?rq=1

Comment: yep, I've read. For example my entity(User) contains (name:String, birth:Date, permissions : List<Permission>). And entity(Permission) contains (metaName:String, createdDate:Date). Is is possible to filter by nested columns too ? like : props(user.name, user.permissions.createdDate) ?